# How do you read text (.txt) files in RISC V (using RARS simulator)?

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32, rars-simulator

I have a text file called **dna.txt** which contains ***ACGGTGCTGTATCCATATCCGTTAACTCTCTTGTGTCACC***. I want to count the occurrences of characters **C** and **G** in the text file, and the length of the original string.

I want the program to read the input from a text file in the same folder as it is saved (on Windows).

Comment: Under what OS?  e.g. Linux, or a simulator like RARS which provides its own set of toy system calls?  RISC-V is just a CPU architecture, it doesn't define system calls because that's something other software provides.  If you're using a real OS that a C compiler can target, a program using `open(O_RDONLY)` and `read` system calls should compile to asm you can look at.  (And you can inline the system calls if you want.)  Or use libc stdio functions.  POSIX `read` returns a length in bytes.

Comment: If you're writing in asm for performance reasons, I'm not sure if an SWAR bithack can be effective here to process 4 bytes at once.  If you're targeting a RISC-V with vector extensions, that should well, comparing bytes and adding in elements where there was a match.  Horizontally adding at least every 255 vectors to avoid overflow of byte accumulators.

Comment: @PeterCordes im using a RARS simulator in Windows

Comment: Then use RARS system calls.  https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls

Comment: will read into this. thanks @PeterCordes !